# C Program Keeps returnig 1

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I am writing this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()  
  {
  int t[50],n,i,test=1;
  printf("Donner la Taille N du tableau :");scanf("%d",&n);
  for(i=0;i<n;i++,scanf("%d",&t[i]));
  for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)  
      {
          if(t[i]>t[i+1]){test=0;break;};
      };
  return test != 0);
  }
```

it is supposed to return 1 if the array is ascending but it always return 1

Comment: Could you please post your code without syntax errors, and also post your inputs?

Comment: Please compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) and **use the debugger** (`gdb`) *before asking* us to do your homework!

Comment: where are the  syntax errors  and you you can take any input ex n=5 / 1,2,3,4,5 it return 1  but when you input n=5 / 5,4,3,2,1  it also return 1 when it is supposed  to return 0

Comment: Your compiler tells you where the syntax errors are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't take it prsonally, but this code is ugly. If you put effort into writing nicer code, it will be much easier to read it and to find errors in it.

I would suggest this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int t[50];
  int n;
  int i;
  int test=1;

  printf("Donner la Taille N du tableau:");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  // here you will want to make sure that n <= 50!

  for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &t[i]);
  }

  for(i=0; i<n-1; i++) {
    if(t[i] > t[i+1]) {
      test=0;
      break;
    }
  }
  return test != 0;
}
```

Ad the bug should already be fixed ;)

Answer (score 6):

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++,scanf("%d",&t[i]));
            ^^^ ^^^
```

That increments *i* before scanf runs... Do instead

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
    scanf("%d",&t[i])
}
```

The *for* loop

```
for(INIT ; COND ; INCREMENT) ACTION;
```

is equivalent to

```
INIT;
while (COND) {
   ACTION;
   INCREMENT;
}
```

In your program, the actual *action* was part of INCREMENT, and done after `i++` (commas separated statements are evaluated and executed from left to right), the `0` value was skipped, and moreover `t[n]` was written to, `n` being logically out of bounds (since it is not a problem while `n` is <=49).

<sup>Note that INIT and INCREMENT are conventions, since you may do a lot of things there that are neither initializations, nor increments! - as you did actually</sup>

Below, a version that use only one loop, no array and less variables, followed with explanations

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(){
  int n,v,previous = INT_MIN; // INT_MIN: minimal int value
  printf("Donner N le nombre de valeurs :");
  scanf("%d",&n);

  while (n-- > 0) {
     scanf("%d", &v);
     if (v < previous) return 0;
     previous = v;
  }
  return 1;
}
```

Explanations

- `previous` is assigned the lowest possible integer value
- `while (n-- > 0)` ensure n is initially > 0, will loop n times
- read a value `v`, if `v < previous` that means the sequence is not ascending
- return directly 1 or 0

*Bon courage* :-)